# Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Updates: put one mvc4 solution to another mvc4 solution!

I search same question on stackoverflow ,but it didn't work! so I ask again!

> Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)' failed.

Stack trace:

> [MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)' failed.]
>      WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +112
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)' failed..]
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +547
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)' failed..]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930508
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

my project environment is vs2013、mvc4

Answer (score 3):

i've solved the problem in installing this package: Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
```

if it could help you.